# Access - Report to show subform results (Join table)

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm a little bit lost with this one. I have a subform, which shows records based on my combobox selection. This is done like this (code is called from Combobox After_Update):

```
Sub ShowResults1()

 With Forms![MYForm].RecordsetClone
      .FindFirst "[ID] = " & Forms![MyForm]![CmbSearch]

      If Not .NoMatch Then
         If Forms![MyForm].Dirty Then Forms![MyForm].Dirty = False
         Forms![MyForm].MySubfom.SourceObject = "MySubform"
         Forms![MyForm].Bookmark = .Bookmark

      End If

 End With

End Sub
```

Main form is bound to a join table, this is It's recordsource (It is linked to 2 tables via ID's in It):

```
SELECT JoinTable.*, Table1.IDx AS IDx_Table1, Table1.Field1, Table1.Field2, Table1.Field3, Table2.IDy AS IDy_Table2, Table2.Field1, Table2.Field2, Table2.Field3
FROM Table2 INNER JOIN (Table1 INNER JOIN JoinTable ON Table1.IDx = JoinTable.IDx) ON Table2.IDy = JoinTable.IDy;
```

When upper code is executed, I get a results in subform that matches criteria, so this works fine.

Now, what I want is to have a report, that will show exactly what subform allready shows. Is this too complicated, or is there any simple solution ?

EDIT:

I have created a new query (named "SearchReport"):

```
   SELECT Table2.IDy, Table2.Field1, Table2.Field3
    FROM Table2 INNER JOIN (Table1 INNER JOIN Join_Table ON Table1.IDx = JoinTable.IDx) ON Table2.IDy = JoinTable.IDy
    WHERE JoinTable.IDy=3;
```

This query successfully shows records that I want, but only with ID 3. Now I removed "WHERE JoinTable.IDy=3" from Query so that I can show records based on my combobox. This is how I tried opening report:

```
   DoCmd.OpenReport "MyReport", acViewReport, "SearchReport", WhereCondition:="JoinTable.IDy =" & Forms![MyForm]![CmbSearch]
```

But when Report is opened, Access keeps asking about entering parameter value of IDy. Even If I enter 3, there are all records shown from that query. What Is wrong ??

Comment: You would use the same source for the report as the sub form

Comment: I can't do that, subform is not listed under any of available recordsources. I believe because subform's recordsource is based from query (from JoinTable and Table1). Please rather take a look at my EDIT, I think I'm on right path.

Comment: try, DoCmd.OpenReport "SearchReport", acViewPreview,,"idy=" & Forms![MyForm]![CmbSearch]   and remove WHERE JoinTable.IDy=3; from query

Comment: @nazark, thanks for response, I hve solved my problem allready. Your sugestion however didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I had to select records from Query that I posted in edit (full code for command button_click event - button on form):

```
   Dim sql As String

         sql =  "SELECT Table2.IDy, Table2.Field1, Table2.Field3" & _
" FROM Table2 INNER JOIN (Table1 INNER JOIN Join_Table ON Table1.IDx =" & _                   

"JoinTable.IDx) ON Table2.IDy = JoinTable.IDy"  & Forms![MyForm]![CmbSearch] DoCmd.OpenReport "APO_IIS", acViewReport

       Reports![Myreport].RecordSource = sql
```

Answer (score 1):

Both *forms* and *reports* have a `Record Source` property.

In this `Record Source` property you can specify a table, a query, or a plain SQL statement which is your case.

In VBA, if your Subform is opened and displaying the right information, you can just say `MyReport.RecordSource = MySubForm.RecordSource`.

---

But the most proper way to achieve what you want is this :

In the code of your report, add this public sub :

```
Public Sub Open_This_Report(strSQL)
    Me.RecordSource = strSQL
End Sub
```

In your form, add a button, with this ClickEvent :

```
Private Sub myButton_Click()
    DoCmd.OpenReport "name_of_the_report", acViewNormal
    Call Report_name_of_the_report.Open_This_Report(me!SubFormName.Form.RecordSource)
    'or
    Call Report_name_of_the_report.Open_This_Report("specific SQL query")
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, subform is displaying right information, but your first suggestion didn't work (MyReport.RecordSource = MySubForm.RecordSource). I tried this in button_click event - error "method or data member not found". On report_Load event works, but still shows all records from that subform, not just matched records. Now I will test your second suggestion.

Comment: The _first suggestion_ was a broad example, you have obviously to adapt it as Access wont accept it like this. The real solution should work neat if you replicate exactly what I have explained

Comment: second suggestion does the same thing, It shows all records from that subform, not what Is displayed on my form. Please take a look at my EDIT, I think that is closer to solving my problems.